# Meteor forgotPassword & sendResetPasswordEmail dataflow

Tags: javascript, email, meteor

I'm not fully understanding the process for processing a 'forgot password' request from the user. Just looking for a little clarification.

On the client you take the user's email and pass that to `Accounts.forgotPassword` which triggers a call to `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` on the server. `Accounts.forgotPassword` only takes email as an argument.

So `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` is triggered which actually sends the email to the user, but that's looking for a `userId`...

Just confused by the logic there. Why not just call sendResetPasswordEmail from the client with an email and a userId as arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to note that `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` can only be called from the server, and is automatically called for you as the result of the call to `Accounts.forgotPassword`. So in general you don't need to directly call it, however you probably do want to customize the email (from, subject, body) via [Accounts.emailTemplates](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_emailtemplates).

Of course, you could call `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` via a method but consider the most common use case:

I'm a user of the system, but I'm not logged in (no `Meteor.userId()`). I have an email which is attached to my account. I want to get a reset password email based only on that information. And that's exactly what `Accounts.forgotPassword` does for you. How convenient!

Note also that by requiring an email on a route that has to be exposed to the public, you are also inherently filtering out baddies which don't know the emails of your users.

Comment: Thank you David. So I call `Accounts.forgotPassword` and that triggers `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail` which I define on the server like this `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail(userId, [email]);`. Which I totally get. But where/how am I getting `userId`?

Comment: Don't define your own `Accounts.sendResetPasswordEmail`. It is already defined and will be called for you. I promise. :) Do customize what gets sent out with `Accounts.emailTemplates`.

Comment: OH! That was my disconnect. Since the docs list that method I thought I would have to define it myself on the server but it's just there for reference. No wonder I can't find examples of that method's use on the server. Thank you : )